# Problem with bluetooth turning on in 12.04(Kernel 3.2.0-34 generic) on Dell insprion 1520

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell, bluetooth

I've Dell inspiron 1520 Laptop and have installed 12.04 Ubuntu in it, I'm trying to turn on the bluetooth device on the system, In the notification bar it shows, bluetooth is turned on and under system setting > bluetooth it shows bluetooth is disabled, the soft buttons in the settings don't respond.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Following are some commands and their output to aid resolve the issue.

```
sheetal@sheetal-Inspiron-1520:~$ hcitool dev
Devices :

sheetal@sheetal-Inspiron-1520:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)

sheetal@sheetal-Inspiron-1520:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: no
     Hard blocked: no

sheetal@sheetal-Inspiron-1520:~$ dpkg --get-selections
blueman                install
bluetooth              install
bluez                  install
bluez-alsa             install
bluez-cups             install
bluez-gstreamer        install

sheetal@sheetal-Inspiron-1520:~$ ps -el | grep blue
5 S     0  1052     1  0  80   0 -  1185 poll_s ?        00:00:00 bluetoothd

sheetal@sheetal-Inspiron-1520:~$ lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             158438  10 bnep,rfcomm
```